# Border bottom issue with Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am using an image as border for bottom only. It works fine in FF but not in Chrome.

In Chrome it is taking the effect for 4 directions ie top left bottom right

My code is

```
.aboutbg .menu-box-content-wrapper {
  border-bottom-width: 5px;
  -webkit-border-image:url(../images/about-text-bg-box.png) 6 repeat;
  -moz-border-image:url(../images/about-text-bg-box.png) 6 repeat;
  border-image:url(../images/about-text-bg-box.png) 6 repeat;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

In firefox, I can see the border bottom image only but in Chrome I can see the border image in all directions.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also provide your HTML code?

Comment: Also, your images are coming from relative path, so add them in a fiddle with absolute links to see the issue with better clarity.

Comment: hmm...ok I will create a fiddle . Yes it is bit hard to see without an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `border-width: 0 0 5px;` instead of `border-bottom-width: 5px;`.

Check [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/eqpt5/195/)

Comment: Awesome Ketan. Thank you so much for your help. That's the trick. Thanks once again.